# 500 Internal Server Error JsonResult mvc asp.net

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

trying to create a cascading dropdownmenu with jsonresult and ajax, but i cant see why am i getting 500 Internal Server Error. The error occurs above the following method :

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetModels(string brandID="")
    {
        List<Model> models = new List<Model>();
        int ID = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(brandID, out ID))
        {
            using (CarsEntities1 dc = new CarsEntities1())
            {
         models = dc.Models.Where(a => a.Brand_ID == ID).OrderBy(a =>a.Model_name).ToList();  
            }
        }
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {

            return new JsonResult
            {
                Data = models,
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
        }
        else
        {
            return new JsonResult
            {
                Data = "Not valid request",
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
        }
    }
```

I use the method to pass a list of items into DropDownMenu and try to output the list by the following code  :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //if (typeof ($) == 'function') alert('jQuery is loaded.');
        $("#brand_Brand_ID").change(function () {
            // this will call when Brand Dropdown select change
            var brandID = parseInt($("#brand_Brand_ID").val());
            if (!isNaN(brandID)) {
                var ddModel = $("#Model_ID");
                ddModel.empty(); // this line is for clear all items from Model dropdown
                ddModel.append($("<option></option").val("").html("Select model"));
                // Here I will call Controller Action via Jquery to load Model for selected Brand
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("GetModels","ModelSpec")",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: { brandID: brandID },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data != null && data.success) {
                            $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                                ddModel.append(
                                        $("<option></option>").val(val.Model_ID).html(val.Model_name)
                                    );
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Fail");

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

All i get is the following :
GET http://localhost:2508/ModelSpec/GetModels?brandID=2 500 Internal Server Error jquery-1.7.1.js (line 8102)

Also i noticed the error doesnt occur when theres no data passing through the GetModels method. And sometimes i get :
GET /ModelSpec/GetModels?brandID=5  401 Unauthorized

As soon as GetModels returns anything the error occurs else not.

`The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for
 operations that require a connection`

Stacktrace :
http://pastebin.com/3aXg7YiM

Comment: Could you paste the error description? It will be available in the error callback or even using developer tools.

Comment: Also, you can put breakpoints in the action to see where it fails

Comment: You can replace `string brandID=""` in method declaration with `int brandID`. Then you can remove this control: `int.TryParse(brandID, out ID)`. Maybe it will solve the problem but probably not. Could you give a try?

Answer (score 2):

You need to move your return statements inside the using block
The Db context is disposed before you return statement is executed

```
public JsonResult GetModels(int brandID)
{
    List<Model> models = new List<Model>();

    using (CarsEntities1 dc = new CarsEntities1())
    {
       models = dc.Models.Where(a => a.Brand_ID == brandID).OrderBy(a =>a.Model_name);
       if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
       {
           return new JsonResult
           {
                Data = models.ToList(),
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
           };
        }  
    }

    return new JsonResult
    {
        Data = "Not valid request",
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    };    
}
```

Comment: Tried that but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2):

json return type has to be primitive, so i changed the code accordingly(swap List to String[] and OrderBy to Select:

```
public JsonResult GetModels(int brandID)
{
 String[] models;

using (CarsEntities1 dc = new CarsEntities1())
{
   models = dc.Models.Where(a => a.Brand_ID == brandID).Select(a=> a.Model_name).toArray();
   if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
   {
       return new JsonResult
       {
            Data = models,
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
       };
    }  
}

return new JsonResult
{
    Data = "Not valid request",
    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
};    
}
```